# How to round numbers on x-axis in ggplotly/plotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, tidyverse, ggplotly

How can I round up years on axis, I applied `as.integer()` function, but it does not work. Usually, I use `scale_x_continuous(breaks=2015,2022,2))` in case of ggplot, but now I need something same for ggplotly/plotly

[image]

Comment: How about you round the values in your dataFrame, upstream? Maybe a new variable YearRound0 so you keep all information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to format the date column as date. Assuming you only have the year in your data frame, you can just set it to 1st Jan of each year, e.g.:

```r
# Generate some data
dat  <- data.frame(
    val  = 0:10,
    Year = 2010:2020
)
# Get year as date
dat$year_date  <- as.Date(
    format(
        as.Date(
            as.character(dat$Year), format = "%Y"
        ),
        "%Y-01-01"
    )
)

head(dat, 2)
#   val Year  year_date
# 1   0 2010 2010-01-01
# 2   1 2011 2011-01-01
```

Now you can create the plot using `scale_x_date()`:

```r
p  <- ggplot(dat, aes(year_date, val)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y")

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]